# Wordpress get thumbnail of child page without content?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to show the child pages in wordpress of lets say page "A", and only show the featured image of each child page without the content or the title showing up..

Right now I have this as my code

```
<div id="primary" class="full-width">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php query_posts(array('post_parent' => 7, 'post_type' => 'page')); while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(large); ?>
                </a>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <!-- Else Don't show anything -->
            <?php } ?>
         <?php } ?>
...
    </div>
</div>
```

Everytime though below the thumbnail is the title of the child page and the content inside of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instance instead of [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). query_posts alters the main query, so for a nested display of posts like this (which I guess is what you're doing, WP_Query is the way forward. Read the manual entries for more details.

So, something like this should do the trick.

```
<?php

$args = array('post_parent' => 7, 'post_type' => 'page');
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if($my_query -> have_posts()) :
    while($my_query -> have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
      // your stuff goes in this bit.
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(large); ?></a>
      <?php endif;
      // end your stuff.
    endwhile;
  else :
    // Do the no posts found message
  endif;

?>
```